# xcode insert a view under a another

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

Hey,
I want to be able to reproduce this effect that when clicking on one of the button in the menu, a view or viewController appears under the menu controller before the uitableview just like in the MarioCooks app. I have been trying inserting a subview below a subview, but I can't seem to get it right. Please need your help. Sorry I would have provided pictures, but being a new member I have no right to. Thx

Answer (score 3):

Try [UIView's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) insertSubview:belowSubview: method.

If you don't want it to be directly below, you can use insertSubview:atIndex:. A view holds an array of its subviews; you can through the (readonly) NSArray property *subviews*.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but I don't know how to proceed with this. As I mentioned before, I thought about using that, but been trying without success. It would be really nice if someone could provide some lines of code to help me.

Comment: Are you referring to the Mario Batali Cooks app? In that case, the appearance of another view appearing (literally) on top is custom-made. It looks like they overrode the 
presentModalViewController:animated:
method, and used some custom Quartz coding to do that.